# Five iterated integrals

Tags: math-mode

Apparently, there are the commands `\iint`, `\iiint`, and `\iiiint` to type iterated integral symbols. To compute an integral in R^4 x [0,T] (i.e. over a 4-dimensional space and time), I would type `\iiiiint_{\mathbb R^4 \times [0,T]}`, except that the command `\iiiiint` is not pre-defined. Is there a way to type a symbol containing five iterated integrals?

Comment: $\iiiint\!\!\int$

Comment: `amsmath` provides `\idotsint`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but that produces two integrals with an ellipsis in between. I'm looking for just 5 iterated integrals. Besides, despite my post I'm not actually not over R^5; I'm integrating over R^4 x [0,T] (i.e. over space and time), and the `\idotsint` command would obscure this.

Comment: @SAM I just tested out the command and it worked, but unfortunately there is that space in between the fourth and fifth integral symbol that my OCD doesn't like. I asked this question precisely because of this very issue. :)

Comment: i don't have any space here

Comment: @SAM: in display math, you need `\iiiint\!\!\!\int`.  (Cf. _The TeXbook_, bottom of p. 169.)

Comment: I am using TexMaKer http://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGfj.png

Comment: After seeing your edit, I’d say that `\idotsint_{\mathbb R^4 \times [0,T]}` is sufficiently clear for the reader, and definitely looks better.  Now, really, good night to everybody!

Comment: Just `\int_{\mathbb R^4 \times [0,T]}`, with a single integral sign, is perfectly usable in many contexts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `amsmath` package already provides the infrastructure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\ams@newcommand{\iiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{5}}
\renewcommand{\MultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\intop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\intdots@\else\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>4 \noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi % <---- added
    \noexpand\intop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\int\quad
\iint\quad
\iiint\quad
\iiiint\quad
\iiiiint
\\
\int_{\Gamma}\quad
\iint_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiint_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiiint_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiiiint_{\Gamma}
\\
\int\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iint\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiint\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiiint\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiiiint\limits_{\Gamma}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant allowing any number of integral signs; `\multiint` should only be used with an argument at least 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
%\ams@newcommand{\iiiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{5}}
\ams@newcommand{\multiint}[1]{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{#1}}
\renewcommand{\MultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\intop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\intdots@\else\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \replicate{#1-2}{\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@}%
    \noexpand\intop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \replicate #1 #2 { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\int\quad
\iint\quad
\iiint\quad
\multiint{4}\quad
\multiint{5}\quad
\multiint{6}
\\
\int_{\Gamma}\quad
\iint_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiint_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{4}_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{5}_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{6}_{\Gamma}
\\
\int\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iint\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\iiint\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{4}\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{5}\limits_{\Gamma}\quad
\multiint{6}\limits_{\Gamma}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simply programmation side, why it doesn't work after 5 ? `#1>4`

Comment: Just add more lines with `#1>5`, `#1>6`, etc. You could definitely add a command there to do the work rather than add one line at a time, for instance `\replicate{#1-2}{\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@}`. Each line adds an integral sign more, so if you have 5 lines, at most you have 5 integrals. But I think it could be done more efficiently.

Comment: but #1>4 is verified for 5 !

Comment: @SAM: Yes indeed, but the code that is executed if `#1>4` simply adds *one* integral sign!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti ohh i missed that thanks ;)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Isn't there a trick like `loopcntr` from `loopcntr` i mean some command that take as argument the number of desired `\int` and repeat/append the corresponding number of `\int`? to avoid code repetition it looks like poor code comparing to other languages.

Comment: @SAM egreg can definitely add it. A basic example would be to use `\prg_replicate:nn` from expl3 to substitute all those lines except for the first one.

Comment: @SAM: Keep in mind that counters cannot be incremeted or decremented during an `\edef`; you have to play a cleverer trick, perhaps with `\numexpr`.  But I have to get up at six o’ clock (CEST) tomorrow, so I must go to bed now: I’m sure that egreg is already working on this, and I’ll be  delighted to read his new answer tomorrow! (:-)

Comment: @Manuel it would be great and sophisticated, if those commands exist i don't see why continue using old poor code, unless because of old packages and time issue.

Comment: @SAM I added a version allowing any number

Comment: That's simply great :D, even if i am not going to use more than 5 lol